# what is the best way of learning to write pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

what is the best way of learning to write pseudocode that is very clear (using statements that can be easily understood, doesn't contain syntax that is not very self explanatory) but also similar to code with mathematical operators.
so my question is what is the best way to learn and practice this for my exams.

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo-coding uses many of the conventions of a normal programming language, but is intended more readable by a person. Its really just a step in between writing an algorithm, and writing a program in a specific language.

I advise you to read [this](https://medium.com/coding-in-simple-english/pseudo-coding-101-b623d6b8820). It is very clearly explained.

Answer (score 1):

The most important aspect of pseudocode is readability. Everything should be written in plain English.